# Android Emulator : cannot run commands from PuTTY

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator, putty

I'm new in Android development. I'm trying to connect via PuTTY to Android Emulator with telnet ( in order to emulate events - sms send , location change etc) After I created session on PuTTY and connected , any command I entered - seems no effect :

```
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
help     
<no output after help>
```

I'm running emulator from IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2. What are the  settings on PuTTY connection to be set/checked ?
Any information will be helpful . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the fix for me was in the *Connection >> Telnet* settings. When I had the *Telnet negotiation mode* set to **Active** I had the same problem you are seeing. Try setting the mode to **Passive**.

That is what fixed it for me.